# Spring boot response entity returns empty set

Tags: spring-boot

Response Entity produces empty values. However, when I print on commandLineRunner it works well but gives empty JSON set when I check with postman. I suspect the issue is this code in the controller. Missing something?

```
@Autowired
HotelService hotelService;

    //controller method
    @RequestMapping( value="/getHotels" ,method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<List<Hotel>> getAllHotels(){
    List<Hotel> hotelList = hotelService.getAllHotels();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(hotelList);
    }

    // Repository
    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM hotel",nativeQuery=true)
    List<Hotel> getAllHotels();
```

Comment: How do you inject hotelService?

Comment: It is Autowired in the  controller class

Comment: ok, thanks. Could you also try new ResponseEntity<List<Hotel>>(hotelList,HttpStatus.OK) instead of yours version. Or add .build() in the end.